# How to get out of an infinite while loop in TCL by keyboard events?

Tags: loops, tcl, keyboard-events

I've the following TCL infinite while loop.  I want to exit by pressing a key or timed out by itself.  I can't get the key press to exit.  What is missing in the code for it to work?

```
fconfigure stdin -blocking 0
set time 20000
set start_time [clock clicks -milliseconds]
while  { 0 < 1 } {
    fileevent stdin readable {
        exit
    }
    set end_time [clock clicks -milliseconds]
    set dt [expr $end_time-$start_time]
    if {$dt >= $time} {
        exit
    }
}
```

Comment: You never enter the event loop, which is required to trigger fileevents.

Comment: how do I enter the event loop.

Comment: Is this a GUI or a CLI application?

Answer (score 1):

Specific solution to show a number of screens in sequence, using the space bar to switch to the next screen, and automatically switching screens after five seconds.

First, some dummy definitions to simulate screens. I recommend using command procedures like this to setup each individual screen, but in the actual script they will of course be more complex than these.

```
grid [label .a] -sticky news
proc screen1 {} {.a configure -text 1}
proc screen2 {} {.a configure -text 2}
proc screen3 {} {.a configure -text 3}
proc screen4 {} {.a configure -text 4}
proc screen5 {} {.a configure -text 5}
```

Now, the screen switching mechanism (a basic, simple one). The `nextScreen` command cancels the running timer, if any. Then a global counter, `n`, is incremented (it doesn’t matter if it doesn’t exist the first time, `incr` will create it and give it the value 1). Then we check if there is a command called `screen$n`: if not, the command returns, ending the sequence. If it exists, it is called, and then the timer is set to call `nextScreen` after five seconds.

```
proc nextScreen {} {
    global n afterId
    catch {after cancel $afterId}
    incr n
    if {[llength [info commands screen$n]] < 1} {
        return
    }
    screen$n
    set afterId [after 5000 nextScreen]
}
```

Set the space bar to activate `nextScreen`.

```
bind . <space> nextScreen
```

Call `nextScreen` to start the sequence (or don’t, in which case space needs to be pressed to start it).

```
nextScreen
```

Note: no infinite loop needed (the event loop *is* the infinite loop here). We also don’t need to take any action to start the event loop: it starts automatically in the windowing shell.

**Older, generic solutions to the original problem:**

**GUI application**

You can start the event loop by calling

```
vwait forever
```

(`forever` is just a cute variable name) but in a GUI application you don't need to do that, since it will be started automatically.

If you want to control your script by single-key input, it’s hard to get that to work by using `fileevent stdin`. OTOH, it’s really easy to `bind` a keystroke event:

```
bind . <Key> {
    exit
}
```

If you want to break with just key “k”, you bind to `<Key-k>` instead.

Having the loop end automatically after 20 seconds is easy too:

```
after 20000 exit
```

Putting it together:

```
bind . <Key> {
    exit
}
after 20000 exit
while true {
    puts -nonewline .
    update
}
```

The `puts` is there to show that the loop is alive, the `update` is there to ensure that events are still processed.

**CLI application**

For a CLI application, I really believe you should use Expect if possible. Your platform matters a lot here.

You will need to set `stdin` to not use blocking or buffering:

```
chan configure stdin -blocking 0 -buffering none
```

Then you need to convince the operating system to not use buffering as well (aka “raw input”). On Unix/Linux I’m told one uses `stty` for this. Not having used Linux since Slackware came on 60+ floppy disks, I really have no idea.

For a Windows solution, you can use `twapi` to set raw input mode. Note that you need to flush `stdin` or it will be readable from the start.

(This is tested and works on Win7 and Win10 with `twapi` 3.0.32. I’m not certain that this is the best solution. Note that `twapi` has its own commands to replace `fileevent`.)

```
package require twapi

twapi::modify_console_input_mode stdin -lineinput false -echoinput false
twapi::flush_console_input stdin
```

Run this code before the generic script below.

Otherwise, the code is similar (pressing `Enter` key stops the loop immediately, any other key needs to be followed by `Enter` unless you’ve managed to set up raw input):

```
after 0 {
    chan configure stdin -blocking 0 -buffering none
    fileevent stdin readable {
        exit
    }
    after 20000 exit
    while true {
        puts -nonewline .
        update
    }
}
vwait forever
```

Documentation: [after](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/after.htm),
[bind](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm),
[catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm),
[chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm),
[exit](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exit.htm),
[fileevent](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/fileevent.htm),
[global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm),
[grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[label (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/label.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[twapi (package)](http://twapi.sourceforge.net/),
[update](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/update.htm),
[vwait](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/vwait.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Comment: Unless it's a CLI app then it should be done with fileevent stdin :D

Comment: Updated with a feeble attempt at CLI scripting.

Comment: Thank you @peter.  Your CLI code is almost what I wanted.  The problem is it doesn't start running automatically by itself.  It needs to press a key to start.  The piece of code I'm trying to write is part of a GUI program.  It displays something on the screen.  The person respond by press the "space bar" and go to the next screen.  If no respond, it will go to the screen after 5sec for example.  It keeps going screen after screen until the end of the program.

Comment: proc screen1 {} {  display something on screen,  wait for "space bar" then go to next screen  or time out(after 5s) and go to next screen  }

Comment: @chuk01: it's very strange that the CLI loop doesn't start for you: the after 0 is supposed to take care of that. Never mind, the problem you describe here is easier to solve (no need for a loop). I'll update soon.

Comment: @peter you are wonderful!  Very elegant solution to my problem.  This is exactly what I am trying to do.  Thank you very much.  I also want to say thank you to all of those who answered my question.  This is the first time I am here.  This site is a great resource for programing help.

Answer (score 1):

This is just one another way of getting the expected result, but only with the combination of `Control` keys.

With Expect's `trap`  command, we can handle the signals such as `SIGINT` (Ctrl+C).

```
set loop_var 1
trap {set ::loop_var 0;puts "Resetting the loop_var to zero"} SIGINT
while {$loop_var} {
        puts "loop_var : $loop_var"
        after 1000
}
puts "Out of infinite!!!"
```

Once you press the `Ctrl+C`, the loop will break.

**Reference :**  [Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)

Comment: Thank you @peter.  Your CLI code is almost what I wanted.  The problem is it doesn't start running automatically by itself.  It needs to press a key to start.

Comment: @chuk01 : Sorry. I don't get it. What do you mean by it is not starting automatically?